# Reading a Binary File for Floats and Putting them into an Array

Tags: arrays, c, file

I am reading a binary file for floats and storing them in an array. There is a set of 4 byte floating-point values in the file. However, with my current code, the values of the last two indexes of the array are always read as the same value instead of what the actual value of the last index is.
For example, I am getting

```
array[0] = -123456.123456
array[1] = 123456.123456
array[2] = 123456.123456
```

when I should be getting something like

```
array[0] = -123456.123456
array[1] = 123456.123456
array[2] = 654321.654321
```

I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly in terms of the reading and why I am getting this output.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd; 
    float num; 
    size_t nr; 
    int elementnum = 0; 
    
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY); 
    nr = read(fd, &num, sizeof(float));
    
    if (fd == -1){
        printf("Error opening file");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (nr == -1){
        printf("Error reading file"); 
        exit(1); 
    }
    
    struct stat st; 
    fstat(fd, &st); 
    off_t size = st.st_size; 
    for (int j = 0; j < size/4; j++){
        elementnum++; 
    } 
    printf("number of elements: %d\n", elementnum); 
    
    float array[elementnum];
    for (int i = 0; i < elementnum; i++){
        nr = read(fd, &num, sizeof(float));
        array[i] = num; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < elementnum; i++){
        printf("Before Sorting: %f\n", array[i]);
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Can you produce a hex dump of your input file (e.g. using `xxd`), _edit_ your question, and post the output in a code block here?

Comment: Nitpick: All my files are binary on all my computers. So, unless you know the actual format in that file, you can't read it. In your case, it seems to have the same representation as your particular CPU uses in-memory. This isn't really portable. That said, yes, please provide a [mcve] and, just to make sure, also add some error checking to your read operations.

Comment: What you did is a wonderfully baroque way of reading a file of floats from disk... there's no need for stat, no need for most of the includes. I suggest you remove everything that doesn't actually read the floats from disk. All you need is opening the file, reading, resizing the array when needed. **That is it**. You don't want anything more. And you do that, you'll see that it works just fine. You should only complicate things after the simplest way of doing it works. One measure of simplicity is how many different I/O functions you're using. You need exactly two. No more. Think about it.

Comment: And you don't need anything system specific either - no need for POSIX headers. Use plain C standard library, and you need exactly two headers: `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the value returned by each read. Since you read one byte out of the file right after you open it (apparently just to validate that one read works) and do not rewind, your loop is trying to read one more value than is available.  If you check the read on the final iteration, I suspect you will see that it returns zero.  Since it returns 0, it does not change the value of `num`, so `num` retains the value it had on the penultimate iteration.

IOW, stop reading a byte after you open.  Instead, just `open` the file and check that `open` was successful.  Then read until read returns 0 or -1.  If `read` returns 0 before you expect it or if it returns -1, then print an error message.